# Using log4net with Unity IoC

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net, unity-container

I'm trying to configure log4net with Unity, but I don't think I fullu understand what needs to be done.

In particular I can't figure how to log the %thread such that it logs the name of the class.

I created a MyLog4Net : ILogger class, but I don't get how I pass this class the calling class and how this relates to the logger name in the  config section ( < logger name="File" > ).

If someone could explain this to me I'd be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern for logging the name of the logger (I assume you want to use the class as logger name) is not %thread but %logger. You can find more samples [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719346/using-ninject-or-some-other-container-how-can-i-find-out-the-type-that-is-reque) discusses the same problem of how to pass the type requesting injection to the logger using Ninject. Not sure how you would do this with Unity though.