# Dependency Injection vs Service Location

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, dependency-management, service-locator

I am currently weighing up the advantages and disadvantages between DI and SL. However, I have found myself in the following catch 22 which implies that I should just use SL for everything, and only inject an IoC container into each class.

**DI Catch 22:**

Some dependencies, like Log4Net, simply do not suit DI. I call these meta-dependencies and feel they should be opaque to calling code. My justification being that if a simple class 'D' was originally implemented without logging, and then grows to require logging, then dependent classes 'A', 'B', and 'C' must now somehow obtain this dependency and pass it down from 'A' to 'D' (assuming 'A' composes 'B', 'B' composes 'C', and so on). We have now made significant code changes just because we require logging in one class.

We therefore require an opaque mechanism for obtaining meta-dependencies. Two come to mind: Singleton and SL. The former has known limitations, primarily with regards to rigid scoping capabilities: at best a Singleton will use an Abstract Factory which is stored at application scope (ie. in a static variable). This allows some flexibility, but is not perfect.

A better solution would be to inject an IoC container into such classes, and then use SL from within that class to resolve these meta-dependencies from the container.

Hence catch 22: because the class is now being injected with an IoC container, then why not use it to resolve all other dependencies too?

I would greatly appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: Your comment about needing to pass it down from A->B->C->D suggests you are confusing run-time and creation time. See http://misko.hevery.com/2009/03/30/collaborator-vs-the-factory/comment-page-1/

Comment: Great comment WW, that has honestly helped to rectify a large mental block I've been having re DI.

Comment: IMHO service location is poor man's inversion of control, it gives you some of the benefit of a proper IoC but by not being explicit defeats many of its benefits as well. Dependency injection is where its at.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Because the class is now being injected with an IoC container, then why not use it to resolve all other dependencies too?

Using the service locator pattern completely defeats one of the main points of dependency injection. The point of dependency injection is to make dependencies explicit. Once you hide those dependencies by not making them explicit parameters in a constructor, you're no longer doing full-fledged dependency injection.

These are all constructors for a class named `Foo` (set to the theme of the Johnny Cash song):

Wrong:

```
public Foo() {
    this.bar = new Bar();
}
```

Wrong:

```
public Foo() {
    this.bar = ServiceLocator.Resolve<Bar>();
}
```

Wrong:

```
public Foo(ServiceLocator locator) {
    this.bar = locator.Resolve<Bar>();
}
```

Right:

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

Only the latter makes the dependency on `Bar` explicit.

As for logging, there's a right way to do it without it permeating into your domain code (it shouldn't but if it does then you use dependency injection period). Amazingly, IoC containers can help with this issue. Start [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx).

Comment: I completely agree that the latter is the cleanest and most explicit. However, don't you agree that classes like Log4Net shouldn't be injected?

Comment: @Lawrence Wagerfield: I don't agree. Please see my edit on the right way to handle logging. Either inject them, or use an AOP approach.

Comment: @Jason: I wouldn't say that the *main* point of DI is to make dependencies explicit, rather to make them injectable.  Most people see ctor/property injection as an unquestionable benefit, but not all.  I think the original poster brings up a valid point from a pragmatic perspective.

Answer (score 6):

Service Locator is an anti-pattern, for reasons excellently described at http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx.  In terms of logging, you could either treat that as a dependency just like any other, and inject an abstraction via constructor or property injection.

The only difference with log4net, is that it requires the type of the caller that uses the service.  [Using Ninject (or some other container) How can I find out the type that is requesting the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719346/using-ninject-or-some-other-container-how-can-i-find-out-the-type-that-is-reque) describes how you can solve this (it uses Ninject, but is applicable to any IoC container).

Alternatively, you could think of logging as a cross cutting concern, which isn't appropriate to mix with your business logic code, in which case you can use interception which is provided by many IoC containers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx describes using interception with Unity.

Comment: Service location is not an antipattern. It is just a pattern that is frequently used improperly. The purpose is for run time resolution based on variable data. If you have access to the information at constructor time, you likely do not want to use a locator directly.

Comment: For run time resolution based on variable data you have factories - either hand crafted (preferred) or container based.

Comment: factories by definition are only allowed to return new instances which eliminates the ability to use lifetime scoped objects, once you allow it to return anything lifetime scoped.. it's a locator.

Comment: Not if the factory contains a reference to a container (locator) or is a container factory. Either way, it's desirable to limit the use of locators and they should still be considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: I agree you want to limit their usage but it is absolutely not an antipattern. An explosion of locators could be considered an antipattern just like the explosion of *anything* is an antipattern.

Comment: Everyone links that article about service locator being an anti-pattern, but they don't know when the pattern is applied appropriately. The example given is a misuse of the service locator pattern.  Service locators are for pluggable behavior where many concrete implementations implement the same interface, and you choose an implementation based on some condition, configuration, or data driven decision.  It is true they should be used rarely, but not because it's an antipattern, but rather because the situation where it is appropriate is rare. Like all patterns, it shouldn't be used blindly.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is that it depends. Sometimes one is better and sometimes another. But I'd say that generaly I prefer DI. There are few reasons for that.

1. When dependency is injected somehow into component it can be treated as part of its interface. Thus its easier for component's user to supply this dependecies, cause they are visible. In case of injected SL or Static SL that dependencies are hidden and usage of component is a bit harder.
2. Injected dependecies are better for unit testing cause you can simply mock them. In case of SL you have to setup Locator + mock dependencies again. So it is more work.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes logging can be implemented using **AOP**, so that it doesn't mix with business logic.

Otherwise, options are :

- use an **optional dependency** (such as setter property), and for unit test you don't inject any logger. IOC container will takes care of setting it automatically for you if you run in production.
- When you have a dependency that almost every object of your app is using ("logger" object being the most commmon example), it's one of the few cases where the singleton anti-pattern becomes a good practice. Some people call these "good singletons" an **Ambient Context**:
  http://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/

Of course this context has to be configurable, so that you can use stub/mock for unit testing.
Another suggested use of AmbientContext, is to put the current Date/Time provider there , so that you can stub it during unit test, and accelerates time if you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is regarding the 'Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern' by Mark Seeman. 
I might be wrong here. But I just thought I should share my thoughts too.

```
public class OrderProcessor : IOrderProcessor
{
    public void Process(Order order)
    {
        var validator = Locator.Resolve<IOrderValidator>();
        if (validator.Validate(order))
        {
            var shipper = Locator.Resolve<IOrderShipper>();
            shipper.Ship(order);
        }
    }
}
```

The Process() method for OrderProcessor does not actually follow the 'Inversion of Control' principle. It also breaks the Single Responsibility principle at the method level. Why should a method be concerned with instantiating the

objects(via new or any S.L. class) it needs to accomplish anything.

Instead of having the Process() method create the objects the constructor can actually have the parameters for the respective objects(read dependencies) as shown below. Then HOW can a Service Locator be any different from a IOC

container. AND it will aid in Unit Testing as well.

```
public class OrderProcessor : IOrderProcessor
{
    public OrderProcessor(IOrderValidator validator, IOrderShipper shipper)
    {
        this.validator = validator; 
        this.shipper = shipper;
    }

    public void Process(Order order)
    {

        if (this.validator.Validate(order))
        {
            shipper.Ship(order);
        }
    }
}


//Caller
public static void main() //this can be a unit test code too.
{
var validator = Locator.Resolve<IOrderValidator>(); // similar to a IOC container 
var shipper = Locator.Resolve<IOrderShipper>();

var orderProcessor = new OrderProcessor(validator, shipper);
orderProcessor.Process(order);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Google Guice DI framework in Java, and discovered that it does much more than make testing easier.  For example, I needed a separate log per *application* (not class), with the further requirement that all my common library code use the logger in the current call context.  Injecting the logger made this possible.  Admittedly, all the library code needed to be changed: the logger was injected in the constructors.  At first, I resisted this approach because of all the coding changes required; eventually I realized that the changes had many benefits:

- The code became simpler
- The code became much more robust
- The dependencies of a class became obvious
- If there were many dependencies, it was a clear indication that a class needed refactoring
- Static singletons were eliminated
- The need for session or context objects disappeared
- Multi-threading became much easier, because the DI container could be built to contain just one thread, thus eliminating inadvertent cross-contamination

Needless to say, I am now a big fan of DI, and use it for all but the most trivial applications.

Answer (score 1):

We've landed on a compromise: use DI but bundle top-level dependencies into an object avoiding refactoring hell should those dependencies change.

In the example below, we can add to 'ServiceDependencies' without having to refactor all derived dependencies.

**Example:**

```
public ServiceDependencies{
     public ILogger Logger{get; private set;}
     public ServiceDependencies(ILogger logger){
          this.Logger = logger;
     }
}

public abstract class BaseService{
     public ILogger Logger{get; private set;}

     public BaseService(ServiceDependencies dependencies){
          this.Logger = dependencies.Logger; //don't expose 'dependencies'
     }
}


public class DerivedService(ServiceDependencies dependencies,
                              ISomeOtherDependencyOnlyUsedByThisService                       additionalDependency) 
 : base(dependencies){
//set local dependencies here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that people are really saying DI is the only good IOC pattern but I don't get this. I will try to sell SL a bit. I will use the new MVC Core framework to show you what I mean. First DI engines are really complex. What people really mean when they say DI, is use some framework like Unity, Ninject, Autofac... that do all the heavy lifting for you, where SL can be as simple as making a factory class. For a small fast project this is an easy way to do IOC without learning a whole framework for proper DI, they might not be that difficult to learn but still.
Now to the problem that DI can become. I will use a quote from MVC Core docs.
"ASP.NET Core is designed from the ground up to support and leverage dependency injection." Most people say that about DI "99% of your code base should have no knowledge of your IoC container." So why would they need to design from ground up if only 1% of code should be aware of it, didn't old MVC support DI? Well this is the big problem of DI it depends on DI. Making everything work "AS IT SHOULD BE DONE" takes a lot of work. If you look at the new Action Injection is this not depending on DI if you use `[FromServices]` attribute. Now DI people will say NO you are suppose to go with Factories not this stuff, but as you can see not even people making MVC did it right. The problem of DI is visible in Filters as well look at what you need to do to get DI in a filter

```
public class SampleActionFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public SampleActionFilterAttribute():base(typeof(SampleActionFilterImpl))
    {
    }

    private class SampleActionFilterImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public SampleActionFilterImpl(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SampleActionFilterAttribute>();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Business action starting...");
            // perform some business logic work

        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // perform some business logic work
            _logger.LogInformation("Business action completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Where if you used SL you could have done this with var _logger = Locator.Get();. And then we come to the Views. With all there good will regarding DI they had to use SL for the views. the new syntax `@inject StatisticsService StatsService` is the same as `var StatsService = Locator.Get<StatisticsService>();`. 
The most advertised part of DI is unit testing. But what people and up doing is just testing there mock services with no purpose or having to wire up there DI engine to do real tests. And I know that you can do anything badly but people end up making a SL locator even if they don't know what it is. Where not a lot of people make DI without ever reading on it first.
My biggest problem with DI is that the user of the class must be aware of the inner workings of the class in other to use it.
SL can be used in a good way and has some advantages most of all its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old, I just thought I would give my input.

In reality, 9 times out of 10 you really don't **need** SL and should rely on DI. However, there are some cases where you should use SL. One area that I find myself using SL (or a variation, thereof) is in game development.

Another advantage of SL (in my opinion) is the ability to pass around `internal` classes.

Below is an example:

```
internal sealed class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    internal SomeClass()
    {
        // Add the service to the locator
        ServiceLocator.Instance.AddService<ISomeClass>(this);
    }

    // Maybe remove of service within finalizer or dispose method if needed.

    internal void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The user of my library doesn't know I'm doing this, let's keep it a secret");
    }
}

public sealed class SomeOtherClass
{
    private ISomeClass someClass;

    public SomeOtherClass()
    {
        // Get the service and call a method
        someClass = ServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<ISomeClass>();
        someClass.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the user of the library has no idea this method was called, because we didn't DI, not that we'd be able to anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If the example only takes log4net as dependency, then you only need to do this:

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));
```

There is no point to inject the dependency as log4net provides granular logging by taking the type (or a string) as parameter.

Also, DI is not correlated with SL. IMHO the purpose of ServiceLocator is for resolve optional dependencies.

Eg: If the SL provides an ILog interface, i will write logging daa.

Answer (score 0):

For DI, do you need to have a hard reference to the injected type assembly?  I don’t see anyone talking about that.  For SL, I can tell my resolver where to load my type dynamically when it needed from a config.json or similar.  Also, if your assembly contains several thousand types and their inheritance, do you need thousands cascading call to the service collection provider to register them?  That’s where I do see much talk about.  Most are talking about the benefit of DI and what it is in general, when it comes to how to implement it in .net, they presented with an extension method for adding reference to a hard linked types assembly.  That’s not very decoupling to me.