# Making dependency injection optional by introducting a factory?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, factory

So I have a piece of software containing a brunch of service classes. Those services take some dependencies though their respective constructors.

I have designed with dependency injection in mind, but developers who are going to build on top of the software, may not want to use DI. Therefore I have **not** implemented an IOC container, so it is up to the developer to introduce one if desired.

My problem is that the software comes with an administration website, which uses these services.
I don't want to hardcode the service dependencies in the site, because I want to make it possible for the developers to switch them if they want to.

So how should I go about this?

I was thinking about introducing a factory for services, and give it a fixed static location somewhere. Then use it on the site.

```
public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    public static IServiceFactory Current { get; set; }

    static ServiceFactory()
    {
        Current = new ServiceFactory();
    }

    public TService Create<TService>()
    {
        // Creation logic here.
    }
}
```

Developers will be able to control things by setting their own implementation of `IServiceFactory` to the static `ServiceFactory.Current` property.

Is this the way to go?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency Inject (DI) "friendly" library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) library? It is designed to provide an abstraction layer over an IOC container, however you could equally use it to abstract a service factory as you describe, that way your application would be able to resolve its dependencies without necessarily knowing whether they were coming from DI or a factory implementation...

Comment: So, I should ditch the static part from my factory above, use the CommonServiceLocator in the site and get a ServiceFactory from it, which in turn is able to get services with some default dependencies?

Comment: It depends on what you want to require from your library users. You could resolve all of your dependencies using the service locator itself, which might require your users to do some fairly complex configuration of their chosen IoC container; or you could resolve all your dependencies using a factory (obtaining the factory from the service locator), which is easier for your users to configure, but they might have to implement or extend the factory themselves...

Answer (score 2):

Two things I would like to note.

- What you are proposing is not Dependency Injection, rather Service Location. [They are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985455/dependency-injection-vs-service-location).
- Ideally dependency injection is fully transparent to a developer. I.e. the true dependencies enter through the constructor and not via an indirection.

Comment: Yea, I know :) Trying to find some sort of middle ground.