# Cannot Inject Dependencies into Asp.net MVC 4 Web API Controller using Windsor Container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api, ioc-container

I am unable to configure Windsor Container with asp.net web api, though it working fine with regular controller(IController).

I have regular controller and api controller in same project.

Here is the code for regular controller which working fine:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Controller Factory class for instantiating controllers using the Windsor IoC container.
    /// </summary>
    public class WindsorControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
        public WindsorControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            var controller = (IController)container.GetService(controllerType);
            return controller;
        }

}
```

and in global.asax.cs

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
  container.Register(Component.For<IControllerActivator>().ImplementedBy<WindsorControllerActivator>());
```

and below is the problematic code:

```
public class WindsorApiControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator 
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
        public WindsorApiControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }
        public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
        {
            var controller = (IHttpController)container.GetService(controllerType);
            return controller;
        }
    }
```

and installer:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IHttpControllerActivator>().ImplementedBy<WindsorApiControllerActivator>());
```

however, i am never able to execute WindsorApiControllerActivator.

when, i put debugger in WindsorControllerActivator it work as expected, but for WindsorApiControllerActivator it never get executed.

your help will be appreciated

Comment: How do you register your container as the dependencyresolver?

Comment: Why you customize WindsorApiControllerActivator whereas I don't see any special treatment?

Comment: Cuong le: because i using Nhibernate Session object in the api controllers <br />   public ISession NSession { get; set; }
        public VendorController(ISession session)
        {
            NSession = session;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        [HttpPost]
        public IList<SearchResultViewModel> Search(SearchViewModel model)
        {
            IList<SearchResultViewModel> searchResultViewModels = SearchVenues(model);
            return searchResultViewModels;
            //return "Hello World";
        }

Comment: @nemesv:Any Update from your side

Comment: Don't inject the Windsor container into your components: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985455/dependency-injection-vs-service-location.

Comment: @Steven: actually it is brown field application, therefore no other choice then using it:)

Comment: @aamirsajjad: I'm sorry, your `WindsorControllerActivator` is probably part of your Composition Root. In that case it's fine to do so.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613137/114029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code in global.asax.cs, and it works:)

```
 _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
    _windsorContainer.Install(new EventSorbetInstaller());
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(_windsorContainer));
   ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_windsorContainer));
   RegisterFilterProviders(FilterProviders.Providers, _windsorContainer);

  var activator = _windsorContainer.Resolve<IHttpControllerActivator>();

   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), activator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be very carefull to use an IDependencyResolver for Windosr w/o decomissiong/release concern.

Have a look to this implementation
http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/06/04/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver-with-castle-windsor-part-2/
I didn't try it yet, but it seems the way to go w/ current webapi release